# How long cloud9 project stays live?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have created a simple html project on Cloud 9 because i need a free hosting with https support. But suddenly i find that project went offline and i must start it again from dashboard. Does project with 0 visitors per hour went offline or there is an answer in the docs on cloud 9?

Comment: Is there some reason you're asking if the information is in the docs rather than, you know, looking in the docs?

Comment: My inglish is not so good to read docs

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **one week of inactivity**.

I took a screenshot of my project waking-up:

[image]